# Unity animation translation error

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

I am having an issue in unity. I have an animated model made in blender imported into unity. When the scene starts the model is the correct size and is at 0,0,0. When trying to use a java script to play an animation the model moves about a meter and scales by about half, the animation does play on the small model. The model was made in blender and is not anything out of the ordinary, the animations play in blender with out any issues. It was imported as a blender file not an fbx. Trying to import it as an fbx produced too many issues. The import did not cause any issues but two things of note: the rig was imported with -90x rotation and the animations can only be used as lagacy. The java script is not complicated it is only using "animation.CrossFade( "english_hook" );" or any of the other animations. I have tried to see if anyone else on the internet has seen this issue but either they ave not or I am not searching for the right problem. I am fairly new to unity and have moderate exprience in blender. Has anyone seen this kind of issue, know how to fix it or have any ideas?

Comment: One other thing of note, according to unity the model is not actually moving or scaling in size.

Comment: Does the movement and scaling of the model happen instantly the moment you launch the animation?

Comment: I set the "animation" setting on the "animation" part of the inspector to none. With that setting to none the model starts at regular size and posistion. it only moves and scales when the script performs "animation.CrossFade( "english_hook" );". When that occurs it scales and moves before it starts the animation.

Comment: One other thing of note, I tried "animation.Play( "english_guard" );" and the same thing happens.

Comment: One other thing of note, while the scene was running I used the inspector to try and rotate the model, as expected it rotated on the y axis. After the model moved and scaled I tried to rotate it and it rotated using the original position not the new position.

Comment: Looking into my problem, I found that I had applied locRotScale to my mesh but not my rig, after it was applied the model no longer moves and scales.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Unity4? You might have to mark your animation as legacy, open your imported model in unity inspector, select "Rig" tab and set your animation to legacy.